# applescript to build in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, scripting, applescript, automator

Is it possible to write a applescript to:

activate IntelliJ IDEA

make project

I tried:

```
tell application "IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.3.app"
    activate
    write text "^b" -- I have mapped ctrl+b to make project
end tell
```

but it didn't work.

Recording actions in automator and playing them back works sometimes but not always.

Seeing how there isn't much on the interwebs regarding IDEA+applescript. I almost feel, IDEA doesn't support applescript but I haven't verified this claim.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the "System Events" app instead for the keystroke emulation.

eg,

```
activate application "IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.3"

tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "b" using control down
end tell
```

Comment: Is it possible to know when the 'make' ended so I can take the next set of actions after that instead of just waiting for n seconds - don't want to hardcode n.

Comment: Does a build progress dialog or something come up in the UI at all? If so you could use System Events and GUI scripting to check for it - maybe.  Also if the above answers your original question, please mark it answered.

Comment: When scripting against UI elements, I've found that it's easiest to sleep for a few hundred milliseconds between interactions, so that the UI can catch up.